# Count Entries by field in Gravity Forms

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I need to output a count of entries with the Gravity Forms entries section of the backend.
Specifically, I need to count how many entries by 'Exhibitor Name' which appears in the filter dropdown.

I have this snippet which outputs the total number of ALL entries. Any help on how to modify this would be most appreciated.

```
$form_id = 1;

$search_criteria['field_filters'][] = array( 'key' => 'exhibitor_name' );

$sorting = array();
$total_count = 0;
$result = GFAPI::count_entries( $form_id, $search_criteria, $sorting, $total_count );
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 3):

Look this code snippet

```
$startdate = 2015-12-30; //(Y-m-d format) optional
$enddate = 2015-12-31; //(Y-m-d format) optional
$search_criteria = array(
'status'     => 'active', //optional
'start_date' => $startdate, //optional
'end_date'   => $enddate, //optional
'field_filters' => array(
    array(
        'key'   => '3', //this is the field id of your drop-down
        'value' => 'exhibitor_name'
    )
  )
);

$entry_count = GFAPI::count_entries(1, $search_criteria); // 1 is your form id
echo $entry_count;
```